# How to handle answers that include links to Google Play Store apps that no longer exist in that store?

Tags: discussion, answers, apps

Some answers include links to Google Play Store apps that no longer exist in the Google Play Store.

How is it best to handle these answers?

The most obvious solution is to see if the app exists on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org), and if it does, change the link to the appropriate page on F-Droid.  But that only solves the issue for several thousand apps (out of millions).

How do we want to handle these answers that reference apps not available on F-Droid?

Comment: FWIW, this has been covered in previous discussions. The current consensus seems to delete the answers while letting the OP knows that the Play Store links are dead and [they can probably still see the entry if they have downloaded them before](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209390/44325). If they can find and/or edit the answer to preserve the usefulness, then the answers may be undeleted. For anyone else, replacing them with legal & trusted alternative markets is okay. Just be sure that the features asked are still there since devs may provide different versions on alternative markets.

Comment: @AndrewT. Besides F-Droid what alternative markets are legal & considered to be trusted?

Comment: Deleting the answers is a bad idea as one may find the APKs somewhere else (e.g., https://web.archive.org/ or from other users)